# Entity Framework -> Execute and LIKE clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am having a little problem when passing parameters that need to perform a like through to my stored procedures.

This is the code I have so far is as follows:

```
using (GIDSEntities db = new GIDSEntities())
            {
                SqlParameter tvpClientList = new SqlParameter("@CorporateClientList", dtCompanies);
                tvpClientList.TypeName = "TravellerTracking.ClientIdList";
                SqlParameter pFromDate = new SqlParameter("@FromDate", fDate);
                SqlParameter pToDate = new SqlParameter("@ToDate", tDate);
                SqlParameter pLocation = new SqlParameter("@Location", "%" + location + "%");
                SqlParameter pTrains = new SqlParameter("@Trains", "%" + trains + "%");
                List<RailData> international = db.Database.SqlQuery<RailData>("exec TravellerTracking.InternationalRail @FromDate, @ToDate, @CorporateClientList, @Location, @Trains", pFromDate, pToDate, tvpClientList, pLocation, pTrains).ToList();
                Rail.AddRange(international);
            }
```

My stored procedure where clause looks like this:

```
WHERE ((router LIKE CASE WHEN @Location = '%%' THEN router ELSE @Location END)
AND
    ((@Trains = '%%' AND trains = trains) OR trains LIKE @Trains))
```

As you can see I have tried writing the SQL differently to allow for nothing being passed by the user and something being passed.

Nothing I seem to do either in C# or SQL seems to work, does anyone have experience with this or a solution?

Thanks
Carl

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parameter without quotes:

```
SqlParameter pTrains = new SqlParameter("@Trains", trains);
```

In the stored procedure you declare it like this:

```
@Trains varchar(100) = NULL
```

And use it in the query like this:

```
AND (trains LIKE @Trains + '%' OR @Trains IS NULL)
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I have tried that and it didn't work but I have just noticed my schoolboy error..... my code was working perfectly but my spelling of a particular country was wrong thus returning nothing!!! I just assumed it was my code that was wrong. Thank you for coming back to me though